# Cannot install third party tools on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Cannot install third party tool in ubuntu 16.04. I just installed ubuntu 16.04 and the problem is that i cannot install any third party tools including chrome, yumi and other softwares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this. It is the problem (bug) of Ubuntu 16.04 itself. It will be fixed soon. [Source: Ubuntu Official Website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762066/cant-install-3rd-party-software-after-16-04)

Comment: Yes. The omgubuntu link which I have added to the answer says the same. The patch is on the way.

Comment: Yup, i freaked out for nothing

Answer (score 0):

For a quick hack:

I am facing the similar issue and but I am able to do the installation via `sudo dpkg -i <deb-package-name>.deb` and then `sudo apt-get -f install`.

But I suspect, there's a switch to enable third party packages installation.

Comment: Found this: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-deb-software-install-error This is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install programs via .deb files, I suggest to use Gdebi.

It's a lightweight application that is better at installing .deb packages, and is quicker as well. If there are dependencies, it notifies that as well.

In the terminal, type this:
`sudo apt install gdebi`

You can right click on .deb file and select to open it with Gdebi.
If you like Gdeb, you can make it default to have it open all the .deb files in future.
Read this:[use gdebi as default installer](http://itsfoss.com/gdebi-default-ubuntu-software-center/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Search for "Ubuntu Software" in the Ubuntu Software search box and you will find the *Ubuntu Software Center*, install it.

From now on manage your apps installations with this Center version. It looks better and installs stuff like it should.

A good idea is to continue to keep the Ubuntu Software (no Center) for system updates and such.